# Customize menu css wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have a menu in my html - template:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get exactly the same menu on WordPress?
All I recieve is

```
<ul id="menu-side_menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-26"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take references from here.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

It is well explained with all parameters.